# JavaScript/Jquery not are not submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am developing a JavaScript that detects the links in text and opens a JqueryUI dialog box with three buttons "Yes", "No", "Cancel". Everything is working fine. When the javascript detects the link in text it shows up the dialog box. "No" and "Cancel" buttons are working fine. I want to submit the form when user clicks the "Yes" button, but it's not working.
Here is my HTML and Javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function findUrls()
{
var text = document.forms["myForm"]["text"].value;

var source = (text || '').toString();

var urlArray = [];

var url;

var matchArray;

// Regular expression to find FTP, HTTP(S) and email URLs.
var regexToken = /\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})\b/ig;

// Iterate through any URLs in the text.
if( (regexToken.exec( source )) !== null )
{
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Yes",
                        click: function() {
                            $("#myForm").submit();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: "No",
                        click: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        click: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );

    });
}

}


function submitform()
{
    document.forms["myForm"].submit();
}
</script>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
<p>Tes Test Test.</p>
<p><a href="javascript: submitform()">Submit</a></p>
</div>

<form name="myForm" id="myForm1" action="" onsubmit="return findUrls();">
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="dialog-link" value="Check it out." />
</form>
```

Comment: All I can say is : **oy**...

Comment: `$(document).ready()` should not be inside an `if` statement. It should be at the top level of the script. Find a good javascript tutorial, then find one for jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your `onsubmit` is always receiving a value of `undefined`. In order for the form to submit in this case, `findUrls()` would need to return `true`.

> JavaScript does not have a void type, so every function must return a
>   value. The default value is undefined, except for constructors, where
>   the default return value is this.

http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using attribute name as id, use this instead:

```
$("#myForm1").submit();
```

Or:

```
submitform();
```